# how to make RTL background android

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

I m newly in android and making background with gradient from left to right on black to white.
I add reference image to make it.

[image]

If there is any suggestion, please add me.

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a good question** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank for your comment, actually, i m so new person and it's my first work on stackoverflow, apologise.

Answer (score 1):

For drawables , there is an attribute

```
android:autoMirrored="true"
```

..set this ..so when your app locale changes to an RTL support language..drawable will reflect that change

Answer (score 0):

Please add below.

> res/drawable/gradient_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"    
        android:startColor="#000000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/button_radius"/>
</shape>
```

Explain:

> angle

0 : from Left to Right
90 : Bottom to Top
180 : Right to Left
270 : Top to Bottom

> corners

If you want to make the rounded background, add tag : corners

Comment: Thank for your answer. It worked. Btw the android:topLeftRadius & android:topRightRadius change only top conners.
To make all conners, should I have add android:bottomRightRadius & android:bottomLeftRadius ?

Comment: no need add like that.
<corners android:radius="you pixel" />
only add radius

Comment: Thank again :) This answer so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use AnimationDrawable, the most basic way it's to have three color : blue, a gradient blue-yellow and yellow :

In res/drawable create a gradient.xml file (left to right):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FFFF00"
        android:startColor="#0000FF" />
</shape>
```

Then in the same folder create a animalion-list.xml file :

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#0000FF" android:duration="333"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" android:duration="333"/>

    <item android:drawable="#FFFF00" android:duration="333"/>
</animation-list>
```

Apply the animation-list as background to your relative layout :

```
<RelativeLayout:
    android:...
    android:...
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation-list"
    android:... >

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```